# Searching for a specific key in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object, loops, iteration

I'm currently trying to iterate through a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
"coupons":{
    "item1":{
         "id":"155",
         "name":"First Item",
         "value":-5199.6
    },
    "item2":{
         "id":"255",
         "name":"Second Item",
         "value":-424.91
    }
}
```

I want to return the value of each item's id. How can I accomplish this?

I'm programming in JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using an Object with `item1`, `item2`, etc? You should use an Array instead. `{"coupons":[{"id":"155",...}, {"id":"255",...}]}` Then you could just do `data.coupons.map(function(obj) { return obj.id; });`

Answer (score 1):

```
var coupons = {
    "item1":{
         "id":"155",
         "name":"First Item",
         "value":-5199.6
    },
    "item2":{
         "id":"255",
         "name":"Second Item",
         "value":-424.91
    }
}

var ids = [];
for(var item in coupons) {
    ids.push(coupons[item]['id']);
}

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { 'json...' };

for (var key in obj)
{
    var item = obj[key];
    alert("id is " + item.id);
}
```

You can use the `var .. in obj` syntax to iterate over the properties (or associative indices; same thing in JS) of any object. Always be careful that you know about the objects you're iterating over, since some objects, such as arrays, have other properties that you want to avoid iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

each `coupons[k]` will be items and you can get id using `coupons[k].id`

```
var coupons = {
    "item1":{
         "id":"155",
         "name":"First Item",
         "value":-5199.6
    },
    "item2":{
         "id":"255",
         "name":"Second Item",
         "value":-424.91
    }
}

for(var k in coupons){
      console.log(coupons[k].id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var dataset = {
                "coupons":{
                    "item1":{
                         "id":"155",
                         "name":"First Item",
                         "value":-5199.6
                    },
                    "item2":{
                         "id":"255",
                         "name":"Second Item",
                         "value":-424.91
                    }
                }
            }

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.each(dataset.coupons, function(i, item) {
        $("#data").append('<p>' + item.id + '</p>'); 
        $("#data").append('<p>' + item.name + '</p>'); 
        $("#data").append('<p>' + item.value + '</p>'); }
    );

});

</script>
<div id="contentC"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com), which enables you to search a JSON structure with XPath queries. This lib extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and returns an array with the matches, if any (empty array, i no matches were found).

XPath is a standardised query language and pretty easy the grasp. Here is a testing tool with examples; http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator

Check out this working fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/Yc6cc/

```
var data = {
    ...
},
res = JSON.search( data, '//*[id]' ),
str = '';

for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
    str += res[i].id +' : '+ res[i].name +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```